# How to list the properties of a JavaScript object by field name

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I create an object like this:

```
[
  Object {
    Username = "James", Password = "12345", Email = "james@test.com"
  },
  Object {
    Username = "Auric", Password = "12345", Email = "auric@test.com"
  }
]
```

What is the best way to retrieve a list of the property names? i.e. I would like to end up with some variable 'keys' such that:

```
Object = ["james@test.com", "auric@test.com"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: `[]` Array. `{}` Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var data = data.map(function (el) {
   return el.Email
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of objects there, so you'll need to loop through that then return the values you need.

```
    var myObjects = [
    {
    "Username" : "James", 
    "Password" : "12345", 
    "Email" : "james@test.com"
    },
  {
    "Username" : "Auric", 
    "Password" : "12345", 
    "Email" : "auric@test.com"
  }
];


function getProps (key) {
    var values = [];
    myObjects.forEach(function (obj){
      values.push(obj[key]);
    });
    return values;
}

console.log(getProps('Email'));
```